# How To Export A Windows Registry File Using Java

Tags: java

How can one export and import a .reg file which contains all keys and subfolders just like the registry editor export function?

I've seen various suggestions and libraries e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).

They only read / write keys by name which doesn't help with many or varying entries. Can it be done using the [jna library](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/)?

Comment: Probably. Do you have some code yet, or is this speculative? Also, what do you think is in a `.reg file`?

Comment: One can double-click it so that it imports keys to the registry. The content is plain text but there's no need to re-program an interpreter in order to add the contents manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have it kick off a batch file as indicated [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5672/batch-file-scripting-how-to-export-find-and-replace-and-reimport-a-registry-key-xp-win2k3-vista-windows-7/).

```
set rkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
REG EXPORT "%rkey%" "C:\keys.reg"
REG IMPORT "%rkey%" newkeys.reg
```

Comment: It won't let one write to the C:\ directory that way but the solution is good, thanks.

Comment: @jcracgun isn't that to be put in the command line? How can that be interpreted by java? If I were to write the same command in java that is.

Comment: As indicated, you can put those commands in a `.bat` file and have Java run that batch file.